# Number of active queries against a mongodb in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb, mongoose

In the process of performance tuning a nodejs application, I've determined that the application is blocking because of an insufficient number of database connections in the mongodb connection pool.

I want to know the high-water mark for in-flight queries in my application. How can I find this out? Preferably, using nodejs.

Because I'm using  a shared database, I can't use the database's 'serverStatus' for this purpose.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking but does just passing a larger number for the `maxPoolSize` connection option solve your problem? It is 5 by default.   https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/articles/MongoClient.md#connection-pool-configuration

Comment: Yes, I know that passing a larger number for the maxPoolSize will improve performance. What I'm trying to find out is the minimum number of connections that I require in my pool to prevent any blocking on connection availability.